# TeXstudio - Preventing syntax highlighting effects from LaTeX special characters in Lua code

Tags: luatex, texstudio, syntax-highlighting, directlua

Is there way to make TeXstudio ignore the contents of a `\directlua` command when performing syntax highlighting? Currently, it ends up causing highlighting like:

[image: bad highlighting example]

Which is distracting when scanning the file, but worse still, depending on what the contents are, it can lead the highlighting for later sections being changed as well (as in the image). There currently appears to be [an (old) issue](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/236/) open for allowing Lua syntax highlighting. Of course, having the appropriate highlighting would be best, but without that, is there a way I can have TeXstudio just ignore the entire contents of the `\directlua`'s braces (noting that there may be braces within its braces)? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you using magic comments?

Comment: @samcarter, not that I know of. But I don't know much about them, so I'm not sure if the style or a package I'm using might be including them.

Comment: Never mind, the idea I had in mind does not work as expected :(

Comment: This is an open issue and not easily to solve. Related: https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/2162/

Comment: IMO it's best to get into the habit of putting all the Lua code in a separate file (say `foo.lua`), and in the TeX file have just `\directlua{dofile('foo.lua')}`.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, in my case I'm using a Lua function to preprocess some strings for TeX. Basically, putting a slightly complicated macro (reading from a database and altering some text in my paper based on the latest results there) in Lua rather than TeX. As I use it like a regular TeX macro several times throughout the paper, putting it in a separate file defeats the purpose of the ease of using the macro. Of course, I'm sure I could build that macro in TeX, but with my experience with TeX vs a Lua-like language made doing it in Lua much easier.

Comment: I'm not sure how it affects ease of use. Maybe an example would help. For instance you could just avoid underscores in the final Lua function used by TeX, or else have a TeX wrapper around the Lua function. Hard to tell without an example. Anyway it's up to you.

Comment: Another idea: if TeXstudio is smart enough to understand not highlight stuff inside `\verb`, then you could fool it by redefining `\verb` to be (some variant of) your Lua function. :-) Then you can put arbitrary text inside `\verb` and hopefully TeXstudio will not highlight it. Anyway, this seems the sort of thing that you should bring to the notice of the TeXStudio developers (find their mailing list or whatever), because not many people on this site are likely to know the inner workings of a specific TeX editor.